# Can a PowerApps input field "Depend on" a URL parameter?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am trying to pass a URL parameter (e.g. &email=test@example.com) into PowerApps.  I then need to have a dropdown box that uses this value in the "Depends On" field.  For example, I have a dropdown box that connects to my SharePoint List, but I need to filter it based on the &email value I pass into the URL.  Is there any way I can achieve this?

So far, I've only been able to depend an input box (A) on another input box (B), but I am wondering if there is some way to force input box B to show the &email value I pass through?

Thank you

I have tried entering Param("email") into the referenced input box "Items" field but that results in "Expected Table Value".

Answer (score 0):

[Please refer to this articl](https://sachinbansal.blog/2018/06/17/powerapps-canvas-app-how-to-pass-parameter-in-app-url-display-data-based-on-parameter-passed/)e giving your idea how to pass parameter and use it in your app, you can expand from this idea, get the parameter as local variable and perfrom any operation as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the value of query string parameter in input text box, set `Default` property of text box control to:

```
Param("email")
```

---

To filter items in drop down control based on query string parameter, you can write formula in `items` property of drop down control in below format:

```
Filter(SharePointListName, EmailColumn = Param("email"))
```

Then you can show any column value from SharePoint list as display value in your drop down control.